# Number of conjugacy classes in the group of all symmetries of the square.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be the group of all symmetries of the square. Then the number of conjugacy classes in $G$ is

a)$4$

b)$5$

c)$6$

d)$7$

Comment: If you can see this group as a symmetric group $\;S_n\;$ with permutations, cycles and etc. it is pretty easy to answer this...

Comment: (e) $5\frac12$ (f) $-1$ (g) $3+4i$ (h) $\sqrt {-163} $ (i) $\varphi$ (j) all of the above

Comment: And, if you are getting used to group theory, I recommend that you write down all elements of this group and its Cayley table. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you're just asking us without posting your attempt, you may aswell just [google it](https://www.google.be/search?q=conjugacy+classes+of+dihedral+group+d4).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conjugate class in the dihedral group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556508/conjugate-class-in-the-dihedral-group)