# How do I list the conjugacy classes of $D_n$?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

I know that a conjugacy class looks like this:

$C_y = \{x \mid x = g^{-1} y g \}$ where $g, y \in G$

I also know a dihedral group looks like this:

$D_n = \{e, b, b^{2}, ..., b^{n-1}, a, ab, ..., ab^{n-1}\}$

How can I therefore list all the conjugacy classes for the general case?

Naive me just wrote this down as the answer:

All distinct $C_y = \{x | x = g^{-1} y g \}$ where $g, y \in D_n$

Well... that's not very useful. I'm just not sure what I'm supposed to do to answer the question satisfiably.

Here's the original question:

[image]

Comment: This might help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556508/conjugate-class-in-the-dihedral-group

Comment: See also the homework solution [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/math109/hw7.pdf).

Comment: Thank you both. The hw solution was especially helpful.